# Money in different platforms

Tags: marketing, platform

So first of all, let me start off by saying that I am not in this to make money as of right now. I'm a novice - however I would like (in the frture) to be able to earn some extra cash on the side with my games.

I have several ideas for what my first game could be and then I started considering the platform on which my game should run.

So I started thinking

iOS & Android mobile devices already have a built-in store that everyone uses. This means that even if my game doesn't get a lot of attention (and doesn't reach the highest position on the market) everyone would still be able to find my game on the same platform.

How is this possible with games made for web or even desktop?

Are the chances of making money of web and desktop as big as on the mobile market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this could potentially be largely opinion-based, I would say that it seems unlikely that web games are true money-makers, unless you make a Facebook app that rakes in cash ala Farmville or something similar.  Desktop can, especially on a platform like Steam or through a marketplace like GOG.

Consoles probably get the next highest grossing, supposing the game is actually decent.

Mobile - it's a tough gig.  There is a ton of cruft on mobile stores because of the accessibility.  However, if you do actually get noticed, by the store itself (moved to the front page) or by gaming news outlets, you can stand to make quite the pretty penny from mobile games.  It really should be fresh and new, even if it's incredibly simple (look at the Flappy Bird phenomenon).  Puzzle games seem to be doing really well on mobile these days.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response im sorry the question was a bit opinion based but i find it really hard to find actual numbers online for the "biggest and best marketplace"

Comment: Part of this is purposeful on the part of the marketplace owners (Apple, Google, Steam, et cetera).